# Why a zmq REQ-REP not working?

Tags: c++, network-programming, zeromq, distributed-computing

I have 1 master ( using **`REQ`** ) and 2 slaves ( A, B ) using **`REP`**. The master sends a request to one of the slaves and expects a response from him.

The message is being sent to the wrong slave, even if I set the address in the ZMQ envelope. How to specify the slave address? I think I am setting it correctly in master, but it's not working and sending the requests from the master in round robin fashion.

---

**master.cpp**

```
#include "zhelpers.hpp"
#include <string>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t requester(context, ZMQ_REQ);
    requester.setsockopt(ZMQ_IDENTITY,"M");
    requester.bind("tcp://*:5559");

    for( int request = 0 ; request < 10 ; request++) {

        std::string cmd;
        std::cin>>cmd;
        s_sendmore (requester, "B");
        s_sendmore (requester, "");
        s_send (requester, cmd);
        s_dump(requester);
    }
}
```

---

**slaveA.cpp**

```
#include "zhelpers.hpp"

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t responder(context, ZMQ_REQ);
    responder.setsockopt(ZMQ_IDENTITY, "A", 1);
    responder.connect("tcp://localhost:5559");
    while(1)
    {
        s_dump(responder);
        sleep (1);//
//        s_sendmore (responder, "M"); //Should I set this ??
//        s_sendmore (responder, "");
        s_send (responder, "FromSlaveA");
    }
}
```

---

**slaveB.cpp**

```
#include "zhelpers.hpp"

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t responder(context, ZMQ_REP);
    responder.setsockopt(ZMQ_IDENTITY, "B", 1);
    responder.connect("tcp://localhost:5559");

    while(1)
    {
        s_dump(responder);
        sleep (1);
        s_send (responder, "FromSlaveB");
    }
}
```

What is wrong? 
OS: Ubuntu 16.04, ZMQ version 4.X.X

---

### **Update 1:**

Changed the slaveA socket to `REP` but still master is sending the message to slaveA and SlaveB in a round robin fashion. Now, I think am I setting the message envelop correctly to slaveB ? But when I print the envelope, I get this at slave's that proves I set the envelop to B correctly, isn't ?

```
[001]B
[000]
[005]jjjjj
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **slaveA.cpp** ought use the proper ZeroMQ access-point archetype:

```
zmq::socket_t responder( context, ZMQ_REP );    // !ZMQ_REQ);
```

---

### Post Festum: Documentation to be read twice before generating issues

> **`ZMQ_IDENTITY`**: Set socket identity
>   
>   The `ZMQ_IDENTITY` option shall set the identity of the specified socket when connecting to a `ROUTER` socket. The identity should be from 1 to 255 bytes long and may contain any values.
>   If two clients use the same identity when connecting to a `ROUTER`, the results shall depend on the `ZMQ_ROUTER_HANDOVER` option setting. If that is not set ( or set to the default of zero ), the `ROUTER` socket shall reject clients trying to connect with an already-used identity. If that option is set to 1, the `ROUTER` socket shall hand-over the connection to the new client and disconnect the existing one.
>       **`Option value type`**           `binary data`
>       **`Option value unit`**           `N/A`
>       **`Default value`**               `NULL`
>       **`Applicable socket types`**   `ZMQ_REQ, ZMQ_REP, ZMQ_ROUTER, ZMQ_DEALER.`

Sorry,
this sort of **`.setsockopt()`** settings is:
1) this **feature is excellently documented** having all relevant details of operation & possible concepts of use
2) meaningful only **for objects that are not present in your code** at all
3) decide on a functional behaviour that is **not relevant to your code** at all
4) this **feature is absolutely irrelevant** to the hard-wired round-robin delivery of the objects that are present in your code, for the outgoing traffic.

So, read the documentation, it is "enough" and a fair way to professionally avoid generating issues.

### Q.E.D.

Comment: Even it's a REQ socket the request should go there as the the envelop has that address. Correct ?

Comment: Negative, Sir. Rather stop inventing features, that are not a part of ( protocol ) API-specification. It is common to design things rather in accord with API-defined services, not on the contrary, isn't it?.

Comment: I will try and redesign my solution first with the predefined patterns, but the question is till why not, when the envelop has that address. Am I defining the address correctly.

Comment: I changed the slaveA socket to REP but still the master is sending the message to slaveA although I set the address to slaveB, why ?